Get new mail notifications in Outlook just for a specific mailbox
How can I enable new mail notifications just for a specific mailbox in Outlook Version 16.85 for Mac?
In Settings > Rules, there are no rules available regarding alerts (like "Desktop Alert"), so that doesn't work.
